# How to define RAII buffer class with custom memory manager?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

The question below can be a general question about design patterns but, due to my lack of knowledge, I couldn't.

I am trying to implement a RAII-style buffer class (`Buffer`) using a given memory manager class (`MemoryManager`) with interfaces like `open_manager`/`close_manager`/`allocate`/`deallocate` etc.
The `Buffer` would look like:

```cpp
class Buffer {
public:
  explicit Buffer(std::size_t sz) { /* Allocation */ }
  ~Buffer() { /* Deallocation */ }
};
```

But as a condition, the `MemoryManager` class needs to be instantiated, which means that the `Buffer` needs to be able to use the specific manager instance in the destructor.

```cpp
  ~Buffer() { manager.dealloc(/* ... */); }
```

There would be several options:

- `const MemoryManager*` as a `Buffer` member variable like:

  ```cpp
  class Buffer {
  public:
    Buffer(std::size_t sz, const MemoryManager* manager) : manager_(manager) { /*...*/ }
    ~Buffer() { manager_->dealloc(/*...*/); }
  private:
    const MemoryMenager* manager_{nullptr};
  };
  ```
- `const MemoryManager&` as a `Buffer` member variable
- The manager as a global variable

Which options are the best ? or are there any better ways to get this done ?

Thank you.

**EDIA** : About `MemoryManager`

`MemoryManager` is supposed to encapsulate lower-level stateful stuff and there should be a single instance of the class.

```cpp
class MemoryManager {
public:
  /* Interfaces might be like this */ 
  MemoryManager(); // open lower level mem manager
  ~MemoryManager(); // close lower level mem manager
  void Allocate();
  void Deallocate();
  /* etc. */
private:
  handle handle_; /* low level object */
};
```

Comment: Is there only one instance of `MemoryManager`? Is it a singleton? Or, may it be copied?

Comment: Better way would be, in my opinion, to make your class compatible with the _allocators concept_ and make your `MemoryManager` behave like an allocator.

Comment: The global variable should be avoided, to make the manager a pointer, make it easier to test the buffer with mock objects.

Comment: Your idea is somewhat like the c++17 memory resource, may take a look at this:https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/experimental/memory_resource#L132

Comment: @DanielLangr `MemoryManager` should be a single instance, so should be non-copyable I guess. The class currently is not implemented using the Singleton pattern because the pattern is virtually a global variable.

Comment: Storing a reference or a pointer to some external object in your class is kind-fragile since once they become dangling, you can hardly detect it and will end up with undefined behavior easily. Instead, you can manage your `MemoryManager` single instance with `std::shared_ptr` and have one as a member variable of `Buffer`. This won't also hinder copyability of `Buffer`, which is what a reference members do.

Comment: @DanielLangr Can we think of a `Buffer` as a "shared owner" of the manager ?

Comment: @wanwan Sure. Or, if you don't want `Buffer` to be an owner of the manager, then, you can store `std::weak_ptr` as a member variable. The question is then how should `Buffer` behave if the manager is no longer available. It likely should never happen, so you can then throw an exception (much better then undefined behavior).

Comment: If you have a single instance of MemoryManager, there is little point in keeping a pointer to it in every buffer.  It's possible but wasteful. Why not have a singleton instead?

Comment: I want to avoid a singleton as possible because it's almost just a global variable.

Comment: You have a global object. It could be syntactically a singleton, a global variable, or an object on the heap. What exact difference does it make? It is still a global object.

Comment: I agree that `MemoryManager` is inherently global. However a global variable or singleton has the global visibility and introduces hidden coupling, hidden dependencies, etc. Is that acceptable ?

Comment: AFAICT none of these is a problem in practice, not a greater problem than with any other global object anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The OP in the comment is specifing:

> MemoryManager should be a single instance

If the instance type doesn't need run-time selection from an unbound set templates is the way to go. The standard library is using it heavily.
**The below is a very simplify example to show you the idea**. See this link for more information about exception safety here http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm
and here https://www.stroustrup.com/except.pdf

```
#include <cstddef>

struct MyAllocator
{
    static char* allocate( std::size_t n ) { return new char[n]; }
    static void deallocate( char* p) { delete[] p; }
};

template<typename Allocator>
class BufferImpl {
  char* buffer;
public:
  explicit BufferImpl(std::size_t sz) : buffer(Allocator::allocate(sz)) { }
  ~BufferImpl() { Allocator::deallocate(buffer); }
};

typedef BufferImpl<MyAllocator> Buffer;

int main() {
    Buffer b(100);
    return 0;
}
```

The Allocator is injected at compile time, If you have more than an Allocator type you can create multiple typedef and provide a factory method to construct the object.

In the standard library the allocator is a template class as well, for sake of simplicity I just used a char*.

When the allocator class is a template the way the memory is allocated and the object is constructed will impose constraints on the type T. The standard library usually requests that the object is copy constructable, the above naive implementation requires the object to be default constructable. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator for reference.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, "the `MemoryManager` class needs to be instantiated" implies that the manager is stateful . If it were stateless class like `MyAllocator`, I would use your idea.